# DSL : shortcut to apply a function on every element of a collection of a specific type

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to use its great capacities to create a simple DSL. I found that it was possible to create something like the example below when using DSL and I was wondering how it was possible:

```
val oranges = Array.tabulate(2)(i => Orange(i+10)) //Orange(diameter)
// Oranges of diameter 10 and 11
oranges incDiameter 5
// Oranges in the array now have diameter 15 and 16
```

What I don't understand is how we can directly apply the incDiameter function on an array, since we cannot add the function incDiameter to the Array scala class; for my understandings it is equivalent as doing oranges.incDiameter(5) so something like Array[Fruit].incDiameter(5), but since incDiameter is not declared in the Array class, where should it be declared in order for the 3rd line to work ?
My intuition is that there's probably a way to modify how functions apply on iterables of our own classes so the 3rd line of the exemple is in fact converted to oranges.map(_.incDiameter(5)) but I've never saw that anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods:

```
implicit class OrangesOps(val oranges: Array[Orange]) extends AnyVal {

  def incDiameter(by: Int): Array[Orange] = oranges.map(_.incDiameter(5))
}
```

if you want that extension method to be applicable to any type that you can prove is applicable, you can use type classes:

```
trait IncreasableDiameter[A] {

  def incDiamater(what: A)(by: Int): A
}

implicit class DiamatersOps[A](val what: A) extends AnyVal {

  def incDiameter(by: Int)(implicit increasable: IncreasableDiameter[A]): A =
    increasable.incDiamater(what)(by)
}
```

then, if you can provide an implicit proof that there is an instance of a type class for your type, you would be able to use the `incDiameter` method (as long as both instance and extension methods will be defined/imported into the scope)

```
implicit val orangesIncreasable: IncreasableDiameter[Orange] =
  new IncreasableDiameter[Orange] {
    def incDiamater(what: Orange)(by: Int): Orange = what.incDiamater(by)
  }

implicit def arrayIncreasable[A](
  implicit increasable: IncreasableDiameter[A]
): IncreasableDiameter[Array[A]] = new IncreasableDiameter[Array[A]] {

  def incDiamater(what: Array[A])(by: Int): Array[A] = what.map(_.incDiamater(by))
}
```

This would let you call this operation on:

```
val orange: Orange = ...
orange.incDiameter(5) // oranges built-in method
Array(orange).incDiameter(5) // no build in method, but extension method can be used
                             // because we can produce type class for Array[Orange]
Array(Array(orange)).incDiameter(5) // similar to above, we can create
                                    // type class for Array[Array[Orange]]
```

Depending on how much flexibility you need, you can use simple extension method, or
- if you want to be able to use them with many more types and generate implementation
basing on some principles - with a type class. For starters try the former, and only if you will need extensibility go for the latter. If you want to know more learn more about: implicits, extension methods and type classes.

Comment: Quick note, the `val` on the constructor of the implicit class, should be **private**, so it doesn't create its own identity extension method.